# handling bad forms in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a product model that tracks product data. For each product entry, the item number must be unique:

```
#models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    ad_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    item_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    mfg = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    …
```

records are submitted via a model formset factory, allowing multiple record submission on submit:

```
#views.py

def add_first(request):
    FRFormset = modelformset_factory(Product, fields='__all__', extra=30, form=FRForm)
    saved_records = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FRFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if(formset.is_valid()):
            for form in formset:
                if form.has_changed():
                    saved_records += 1
            formset.save()
            messages.success(request, '(' + str(saved_records) +') records successfully added to database.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/b5/add_first/')

    else:
        queryset = Product.objects.none()
        formset = FRFormset(queryset=queryset)
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'formset':formset })
        return render_to_response("b5/addfirst_form.html", variables)
```

my problem is, if one of the records submitted has an item number that already exists, the entire submit fails (throws a ValueError - “The view … didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.")

**in the view function is there maybe a try/except clause I can write inside of the form loop that will allow the duplicate records to fail silently while allowing the others to be saved? Or is there another way I can configure that behavior?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to formset at all, and there is no need to catch any exception. Instead you should be returning the response, which will show which forms are not valid.

The reason that does not happen in your view is simply that the last two lines are indented inside the else statement. Move them back one indent, so that they catch the case when the formset is invalid as well as when the request is GET.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that I wasn't returning a response because my view function was incorrectly configured. Thanks for the succinct explanation.